# Parametrizing a segment

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, parametrization

I was solving some algebra problems but I don't know how to do one of them. The task says "Determine three parametric equations of a segment HL, with H=(-3;5) and L=(2;-7) using a direction vector of module 2"

So far, I have determine the direction vector, which is (-3;5)-(2;-7)=(-5;12), and if it has to be of module 2 it would be (-10/13 ; 24/13). Now I don't know how to do the parametrizations.

Comment: Your point $\left(\dfrac{-10}{13},\dfrac{24}{13}\right)$ is not in the line $HL$

Comment: So what shall I do?

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the vector has to be 2, then, you can parameterize as:
$(-3-(10/13)t,5+(24/13)t), 0\le t\le$(13/2)

Comment: For that parameterization, you want $-\frac{13}{2}\le t\le0$.